Windows stuck after bitlocker recovery after Ubuntu boot-repair
I have a Dell XPS15 laptop which was happily dual-booting into Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 until recently. Here is a rough timeline of what happened:

Laptop ran out of battery
Afterwards, it could only boot into Windows
I tried to repair this problem by booting to Ubuntu 22.04 from USB and running boot-repair (this did not fix it)
I found this answer that explained how to add the Ubuntu boot option (which had been deleted for some reason). I added a boot option for Ubuntu and made it the default.
Laptop now boots into the Ubuntu partition without issue, but when I try to boot into Windows, it starts Bitlocker recovery, then stops and displays a blue screen with "There was a problem. Restart your PC to try again." and error code 8007139f.

I tried installing boot-repair to use it to repair the Windows boot, but the option to repair Windows boot files is greyed out. In fact, it only has Ubuntu available under the "OS to boot by default" dropdown.
Previously to switch between Ubuntu and Windows, I needed to switch from "AHCI" (Ubuntu) to "RAID On" (Windows), which I'm still doing.
GRUB version is 2.04-1ubuntu26.17. I don't know what GRUB version I had before these problems started.
(previously asked on AskUbuntu; I was asked to move here)
Edit, 2 months later: Problem persists. I tried disabling the various "SupportAssist" options which would interrupt the boot to check the memory. Then I made a new boot option, which used the same boot as the existing windows boot option: "EFI/Windows/boot/bootmgfw.efi". This did not have the same error as before, but immediately brought up a black screen with 3 options: F1 to reboot, F2 to boot into setup, and F5 to run diagnostics. None of them booted into windows.
I made a third Windows boot option, again with the same efi, and this one has the same behaviour as the first: it shows a "Preparing bitlocker recovery" screen, then the same blue screen with error code 8007139f.

The error code indicates a problem with the TPM, (the chip that holds your keys.)
Depending on your UEFI, there should be an option to wipe your TPM keys, (WARNING: PLEASE HAVE YOUR BITLOCKER KEY ON HAND. AS WIPING THE TPM WILL LOCK WINDOWS, REQUESTING FOR THE CODE.)
Try this.

Boot into the BIOS and navigate to "Security"
Look for an option regarding a TPM.
Select an option regarding Clearing the TPM.
Save and reboot, and confirm all prompts.
Then in Windows, use your BitLocker Key to unlock Windows.

--! Reminder: BitLocker is dangerous. ALWAYS have your recovery key in any case. I'm not reponsible for loss of data. SO PLEASE PLEASE P L E A S E have your recovery key. !--

I've never had any keys for any part of the system. At this point if the Windows partition gets ruined that's fine as long as (a) the Ubuntu partition is intact, and (b) I can reinstall a working Windows partition. If I clear the TPM but don't have any keys, will I be able to just do a fresh install?

Yes. You can just reinstall Windows by deleting the Windows partition in Ubuntu and just reinstalling Windows, you will lose everything tho.
